# Universal Analytics: target DOM element with dynamic ID or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Requirement: capture navigation menu click

Current setup:

TAG 1: **Global Click Listener** with a single firing rule for all pages that is,

```
{{url}} matches RegEX .*
```

TAG 2: **Menu Click Tracking** - Custom HTML Tag type with a single firing rule for all pages and HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#top_nav_menu a').click(function(){
  var target = event.target;
  var parentElem = $(target).parent();
  var targetHref = $(target).attr("href");
  var targetClass= $(parentElem).attr("class");

  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'navigation',
      'eventAction': targetClass,
      'eventLabel': targetHref
  });
});

</script>
```

TAG 3:  **Event - Menu Click** - Universal Analytics tag type, with a firing rule:

```
{{event}} equals navigation
```

Track type: **Event**

```
Category: {{event}}
Action: {{event action}}
Label: {{event label}}
```

Macros:

1. event action - Data Layer Variable macro type

Data Layer Variable Name : eventAction

1. event label - Data Layer Variable macro type

Data Layer Variable Name : eventLabel

What is happening: Currently the **Global Click Listener** and **Menu Click Tracking** fires correctly but **Event - Menu Click** fails. I am assuming its because am not targetting the DOM element correctly. The DOM structure is like this:

```
<nav id="top_nav_menu">
  <ul class="no-list">
    <li id="about" class="about"><a href="link-value">about</a></li>
    <li id="services" class="services"><a href="link-value">services</a></li>
    <li id="work" class="work"><a href="link-value">work</a></li>
    <li id="contact" class="contact"><a href="link-value">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I cannot alter the HTML or add classes, how do I make sure that the **Event - Menu Click** tag fires and the correct dataLayer value is pushed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass "event" as an argument to your click handler  to access event.target (sure looks like in in the docs at http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your datalayer push for your "Menu Click Tracking" tag, you are assigning "$(targetClass)" to the Action and "$(targetHref)" to the Label, which seem to be jQuery references (ie. "$(...)") rather than strings. Can you change them to just the variable names, "targetClass" and "targetHref"?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I realized that too, but changing that didn't help. In any case the "Event - Menu Click" should have still fired, since the value for 'event' is passed as a string, and so should have at least passed that if not rest of the values.

Comment: Another thing to point out is that '$(target)' should be 'this' in your function definition because the object on which the method is being invoked is the anchor element (ie. $("#top_nav_menu a")). And then the 'targetClass' would be 'parentElem.attr("class")'. Don't forget to add the 'event' argument as Eike pointed out as well.